# Javascript framework for ASP.Net Webforms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs, webforms

I my organization there is a web application running ASP.Net Webforms. The application has a lot of server side controls and most of the stuff is being done on server side. Due to latency issues we were thinking about implementing a JS Framework. I would like to ask which JS framework will work best with ASP.Net Webforms? We don't want to make two many changes in the application and just want to implement it as a separate layer. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

**Jquery Framework is more helpful for you** [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/) official page